# Is it possible to check if location has been enabled apart from code?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have this project give to me which is in react- native and swift. We are facing an issue in which every time the app launches it checks if the location has been enabled or not.

I cross-checked throughout the code and all the AppDelegates and commented everywhere location permission was being asked programmatically. But still can't find the reason where and how the app is checking the location permission.

So can anyone please tell me if there's any other way apart from programmatically checking if the device's location has been enabled.

Comment: Check the usage / privacy permission keys in into plist file.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke yes did that I commented all the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to your class inheritance.

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() { //As of July 24, 2018
     switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            print("No access")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Access")
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services are not enabled")
}
```

Comment: Sorry Rushabh but it's not the answer am looking for.

Comment: Let me explain clearly what you want so maybe i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your plist file and remove these lines if present

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

Comment: I did, I have commented all the permissions from plist.

Comment: @SimerynDenis check for this line locationManager.requestLocation()

Comment: Tried still not helping